# Disable other formats than HTML in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

We're ending up with a lot of

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template presentations/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>["image/*"], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}
```

in our logs.

The application only does HTML for the moment so I would like all other formats to return 406 (or something). Is there any way to set this once for all render calls? Or do we have to sprinkle `respond_to` everywhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `rescue_from` line to `ApplicationController.rb`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate do |e|
    render nothing: true, status: 406
  end

  # ...

end
```

If I try to access `document.xml` (rather than `document.pdf`) in my Rails application, Firefox shows the following message in the browser console:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/quotes/7/document.xml [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable  29ms]
```

Comment: Maybe this is quite a good workaround, but instead I should be able to respond with status 406.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with a mix match of solutions since I couldn't get `respond_to` to work. This will send a 406 each time someone tries some unsupported mime type.

```
before_filter :ensure_html

def ensure_html
  head 406 unless request.format == :html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Place `respond_to :html` in ApplicationController

Comment: I tried this but it didn't do anything, at least not in development mode. Running Rails 4.0.6. Render is done by default render or `render 'the_template'`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @dgilperez thank you, I will follow your recommendation

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following way

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :html

    def index
      @users = User.all
      respond_with(@users)
    end
  end
```

It will `respond`html all `actions` of `users` `controller`

Or If you want to respond_to for all controller

then add it to `ApplicationController` just do

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController
    respond_to :html
  end
```

and

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @users = User.all
      respond_with(@users)
    end
  end
```

Comment: I tried `respond_to` earlier, maybe it didn't work because we're not doing `respond_with`. Do you have to use both?

Comment: yes please see more information http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2009/08/embracing-rest-with-mind-body-and-soul/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use `respond_with` or want `ActionView::MissingTemplate` to be raised before the action is run (i.e. to prevent models being fetched etc.) you can use [verify_requested_format!](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders#verifying-request-formats) from the responders gem.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  before_action :verify_requested_format!

  def index
    # ...
  end
end
```

Then verify:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: image/*" localhost:9000/users

< HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
```

Incidentally you can also use `respond_with` without passing on a model instance such as:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def index
    @users = User.all
    respond_with
  end
end
```

This however does not seem to be documented as far as I can see.

- rails 4.2
- responders 2.4